# Buffer and intersect using turf.js and leaflet

Tags: leaflet, buffer, intersect, turf

I have 2 geojson feature collections in leaflet. One of them is road and the other one is parcels. I want to calculate buffer for road and then intersect this buffer layer with parcels. How can I do this using turf.js and leaflet. I am a newby in both of them. I tried to write a little script but it does not work. Could you tell me what ı am doing wrong. Here is a little part of my code that I wrote so far:

```
  var buffered = turf.buffer(road, road.width, {units: 'meters'});
  var roadbuf = L.polygon(buffered, {style:myStyle}).addTo(mymap);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this.

```
var buffered = turf.buffer(road.toGeoJSON(), road.width, {units: 'meters'});
var roadbuf = L.polygon(buffered, {style:myStyle}).addTo(mymap);
```

A Leaflet layer is not quite the same thing as a Turf GeoJSON layer.

Comment: Thank you for answer but before I try it I recognized I could not load turf.js properly. How can I do that I looked at Github page and referenced link in script elements but it doesn't work

Comment: Here is a demo selecting points. The polygon and rectangle use Turf, the circle does not. I use the CDN method instead of downloading it. http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/Select/PolySelect.html  Check the head section in the html. <script src="https://npmcdn.com/@turf/turf/turf.min.js"></script>

Comment: it says road.toGeoJSON() is not a function ??

Comment: http://leafletjs.com/reference-1.2.0.html#polyline-togeojson  It looks like road is not a leaflet layer, check the spelling/case, or a question of seeing the leaflet library. Can you show more code?

Comment: See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/264268/turf-js-invalid-unit-error-for-buffer   for working solution.